# "NameError: name is not defined" for user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I am new to python and made a short script to try them out, while doing so I came across and error I've never had for the particular situation before, when I try to define `uN` as a `str` inputted by the user I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Scripts/classTest/classTest1.py", line 14, in <module>
uN = input(str("Username"))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'ben' is not defined
```

The code is as follows:

```
class user:
    def __init__(self, usrName, pWord):
        self.usrName = usrName
        self.pWord = pWord

    def createUsrPw(self):
        f = open("usrName.txt", "a")
        f.write(self.usrName)
        f.write("   ")
        f.write(self.pWord)
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()

uN = input(str("Username"))
pW = input(str("Password"))

usr1 = user(uN, pW)

usr1.createUsrPw()
```

I have used the `x = input(str())` syntax a lot before and never had this error, and the error traces back to line 1, so is `uN = input(str("Username"))` still being considered a part of the class?

when I simplify the code to this it works perfectly:

```
class user:
    def __init__(self, usrName, pWord):
        self.usrName = usrName
        self.pWord = pWord

    def createUsrPw(self):
        f = open("usrName.txt", "a")
        f.write(usrName)
        f.write("   ")
        f.write(pWord)
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()


usr1 = user("Ben", "testPw")

usr1.createUsrPw()
```

with the file usrName.txt being appended to include "Ben   testPw" as intended.

Comment: This error looks like `python-2.x` where `input()` works like `eval()`. Are you sure it's python 3?

Comment: You are not using Python 3, you are using Python 2 here. Check your interpreter.

Comment: also why do you need `input(str())` input already returns a string, if that was your intention

Comment: oh wow I feel silly, yes I am, I must have misclicked when opening it. I'm so used to using 3 that I didn't even consider that.

Comment: @danidee I was not aware of that, thank you! that was how it was written in the first tutorial I looked at so I assumed that was how it should be. I will remember that in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `raw_input` instead of `input` as you are using Python 2.X. `input` works in Python 3.

This code would work:

```
class user:
    def __init__(self, usrName, pWord):
        self.usrName = usrName
        self.pWord = pWord

    def createUsrPw(self):
        f = open("usrName.txt", "a")
        f.write(self.usrName)
        f.write("   ")
        f.write(self.pWord)
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()

uN = raw_input("Username")
pW = raw_input("Password")

usr1 = user(uN, pW)

usr1.createUsrPw()
```

Comment: thank you, yes it was pointed out in the comments of the OP that I was using Python 2 not 3, must have clicked the wrong IDLE, bit embarrassing, I've only ever used Python 3 so I didn't even think to check. I will tick this as the best answer as soon as it'll let me

Answer (score 0):

Use raw_input. This looks like a Python 2 error, I don't think you're using Python 3

You also don't need to call str on a string literal. str("asdf") == "asdf"